# Need GUI to run qemu on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, qemu, kde-plasma

Need GUI to run qemu on Ubuntu server: I need to run QEMU for ARM on a Ubuntu srever. THis QEmu is not supporting a text mode, so I need to install GUI software on Ubuntu server 13.04. Please suggest any that I can do a sudo apt-get install and get started quickly.

Comment: Qemu is emulating a raw PC hardware. Just use it to run whatever operating system or software you want. I don't understand what are you asking....

Answer (score 2):

Are you connecting to the server over ssh? You could just use X forwarding to your local machine.

[See the very good first answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine).

Then you can just start the software and interact with the GUI on a computer that already has the desktop environment installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

For more info, look to this [link](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-gui-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-gnome/)